# Subscription Site CMS

Tags: cms, looking-for-a-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I was wondering if there are any subscription cms's out there which provide good functionality?

I am looking to have a site which has different levels of users such as bronze,silver,gold. They will then be able to access specific content on the site. So articles and videos which are only accessible to certain members.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By "subscription CMS" I'm assuming you don't want to install the CMS yourself, but to use it as a service, right?

If that is the case, and if you want to create access levels to different kinds of content, then Drupal 7 is a good CMS. If you don't want to install Drupal yourself than http://www.drupalgardens.com/ is an excellent host. You can use their free plan to test the solution (the CMS), but you probably want to have support with one of the paid solutions.

Wordpress is a great CMS as well, but I don't know how to limit reading access to certain users to certain content (without installing a plugin). *Note: You can password protect a post, but it's not exactly what you asked...* I would suggest you ask Kevin for a link with an how-to before you spend hours learning how to use it in vain.

In my opinion, Wordpress is easier (to administrate) than Drupal as well.

Answer (score 0):

One of the free ones that has great functionality that is always being added to is Wordpress.  Wordpress allows different users with different access to areas.  A little PHP can customize it even further as well.

Its fairly simple to install and customize and will continue to add great new features...that would be my recommendation.

Wordpress.org and you can download the code.

Kevin